# Soft starter for centrifugal pump

Tags: motor, ac, inrush-current, fluid-pump

Do most manufactured centrifugal pumps come equipped with soft starters, and is it a good idea to invest in one if they're going to be frequently switched on/off?

Comment: A soft-start is often more important for the mechanism attached to the motor. A centrifugal impeller doesn't have the same issues that a complex machine with gears might have.

Answer (score 2):

I have slight experience with residential well-pumps, pool pumps, and pressure booster pumps. None of them use soft start. Those I have dealt with are in the 3HP and less range. Single phase. Service life is OK. I think the centrifugal switch on the motor or the motor capacitors would be the first thing to fail. Maybe motor bearings for ODP motors in dirty environments. If you are dealing with 3 phase motors, I would think that you will get excellent service life without slow start. So I don't think it is advantageous. In a dirty/dusty environment, consider totally enclosed motors (TEFC or TENV).

Some types of single-phase motors do not have a centrifugal switch (permanent split capacitor motors). So a permanent split capacitor motor might be worth it for a motor that is started and stopped frequently. Make sure the motor relay is over-sized and easy to replace if possible.

I think a properly sized, totally enclosed, fan cooled three phase motor running directly from the line power is about as reliable a thing as you will find.

Answer (score 2):

Soft starting is mostly used where direct motor starting is difficult for the power distribution system. It may be needed to minimize voltage fluctuations. You can not get good advice about that without stating the power level of the motor and the location.

Pumps may or may not be furnished with motor starters depending on the power level, the supplier, the type of customer and the location. Industrial supplier practices may differ from the practices of farm, commercial and residential suppliers.

If the driven equipment needs soft starting, it will be something other than a pump and will probably need a variable speed drive.

You will need to evaluate the motor's ability to switch on and off frequently. NEMA motor's have ratings for "maximum starts per hour" "minimum rest time between starts" and "maximum product of starts per hour times load WK^2." NEMA MG1 lists the ratings for horsepower ratings from 1 to 250 and 2, 4 and 6 pole motors. Similar information should be available for IEC motors. Motor manufacturers should be able to provide information or other motors and the use of a soft starter.

Comment: The pumps I'm using range from 0.5 to 1.5 HP, up to 230VAC. Some are also manufactured to be plugged into a standard GFCI outlet.

Comment: I believe that soft starters are never applicable to single-phase induction motors. At that power level and up to 3 to 4 times that power level, they are probably never used for 3-phase induction motors either.